# Accessing anchor with href/Javascript

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, href, casperjs

Testing CasperJS on a system that has an anchor with an href attached to javascript. Doing the usual

```
casper.then(function() {
this.evaluate(function() {
//      document.querySelector('a[id="CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH"]').click();    // works in FF
//  window.onload=submitAction_win0(document.win0,'CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH');

      //eval("submitAction_win0(document.win0,'CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH_1');");
//submitAction_win0(document.win0,'CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH');
//  window.onload=submitAction_win0(document.win0,'CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH');

//      this.click('a[id="CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH"]');
//      click('a[id="CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH"]');
//      self.click('a[id="CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH"]');
//      this.this.click('a[id="CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH"]');
..

});

});
```

None of the above approaches worked. The Git repos for the projects indicate that Casper has a CasperUtils/ClientUtils lib that appears to have a `__utils__` that has a click method which is the way to invoke `href="javascript:foo()"` elements.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to get this running.

If anyone has used CasperJS, and has a sample of code on how this is implemented, we'd be thankful!

Ideally, the end result should be something like:

```
casper.then(function() {
  e=document.querySelector("id['foo']");
  CasperUtilsSomething.click(e);
});
```

Or, if you have a pointer to a test code case that I could run, that would let us see how this is supposed to be implemented.

Comment: You should better read some tutorials before working with such libraries.

Comment: Andreas.  Hi. Thanks for the reply. And I have tried to read everything I could find on how to implement this. Do you have any knowledge of a tutorial that walks through how to implement this. I couldn't find any, including from youtube, the GIT repos, the support forums, mailing list archives, etc.. Any other place you can think of??   I only turned here as a last ditch question.

Comment: "tom" (a.k.a bruce), do yourself a favor and do this tutorial http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/ — that way you'll probably understand much more what's going on here

Comment: Hi Niko  Thanks for the pointer. I'm not sure this is a "understand javascript: issue. Don't get me wrong, more javascript understanding would obviously help, but I'm inclined to think this is an understanding of casper/phantom issue more than anything. We got the same thing up/runing in Selenium/Java with a couple of hours without having to "learn" java!! There appears to be something else that we're missing here with this. But thanks, and we'll look over the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue here is a confusion around the scope of the function. This is the tricky thing about working with PhantomJS (which CasperJS is built on top of) - there are two entirely separate scopes, one of which runs in the PhantomJS context and has access to the `casper` object, and the "sandbox" scope that remote code runs in - anything run in `casper.evaluate()`, for example, is run in a sandbox in the remote context, with no access to the `casper` object or its methods.

So trying to call `this.click()` within `casper.evaluate()` is going to fail - the function you're running has no access to the `casper` instance, and `this` will refer to the `window` object in the browser.

Usually, the way you'd do this is just:

```
casper.then(function() {
    casper.click('#CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH');
    casper.evaluate(function() {
        // some function that needs to run after clicking
    });
});
```

Note also that as far as I know, you generally can't run any `window.onload` code in `casper.evaluate()` - the window's `load` event will already have fired by the time you are running your code.